# xcode iphone change default start view

Tags: iphone, xcode, view

I am using xcode 4.5.2 and I have 3 different views in the application for Iphone.

MainWindow.xib
View1.xib
View2.xib

When the app starts in the simulator View1.xib shows up.
I would like that View2.xib shows up when the app starts instead of View1.xib.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your app delegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {
    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.window setRootViewController:viewController];
    return YES;
}
```

in `.h` add the variable like:

```
View2 *viewController;
```

And add property like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) 
View2 *viewController;
```

Comment: I get a blank page. It seems that I missed something. Do I have to remove the reference of the old window in the delegate?

Comment: is there anything on the view ?

Comment: Yes. Two textfields and a button.

Comment: @Oualid: you have classes for those xib, is it ? or only a xib ?

Comment: I have both .h and .m files for the xib file. It shows up when I push on a button in the view1.

Comment: Then the code is ok, I think you are missing something in your xib or the appdelegate class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19521/discussion-between-oualid-and-midhun-mp)

Answer (score 4):

If you look at your Storyboard, you see a arrow in front the window (left side). You can drag this arrow to another view. You can also check the "is initial viewcontroller" checkmark in the **attributes** section (storyboard) of the desired view.

[image: Xcode Storyboard]

Comment: @downvoter, can you have to courtesy and explain whats wrong with my answer? Especially since its a correct answer.